# Magento 1.9 How to Remove COD via shipping cart rule

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules, cash-on-delivery

I want to remove payment method Cash On Delivery with the help of Shipping cart rule. If cart value is more than 10,000/- Cash On Delivery must be removed from Payment method. I was disabled default COD Module, Now I am using [CashOnDelivery Based on Zipcode](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cashondelivery-based-on-zipcode.html), this module has only zip code filteration, I need to set order limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento does not  have any feature to remove *Cash On Delivery* using ***Shopping Cart rules.***.

Shopping Cart ***only give to facility discount on current cart***  and also *able make shipping charge zero*.There are **no option to remove payment method**

For your case, you should customization at observer class in your custom module

Comment: thanks for you advice, i will try to customize the code.